# simple_form's collection_radio_button and custom label class

Tags: ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to make a star rating form with radio collection using FontAwesome, for this I actually need to change the label classes of the collection_radio_button input generated by simple_form but can't find any obvious solution.

So far I use:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_radio_buttons :rating, [[1, 'Bad'] ,[2, 'Ok'], [3, 'Great']],
                             :first, :last, { item_wrapper_tag: false }
end
```

Which generates:

```
<input id="review_rating_1" name="review[rating]" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="review_rating_1">Bad</label>
<input id="review_rating_2" name="review[rating]" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="review_rating_2">Ok</label>
<input id="review_rating_3" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="review_rating_3">Great</label>
```

But I'd like the labels to have an extra class, like:

```
<input id="review_rating_3" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons icon-star" for="review_rating_3">Great</label>
```

UPDATE: This class is defined statically at: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/tags.rb#L43

Comment: Could try adding `label_html: { class: 'icon-star' }` as an option

Comment: I have tried without success. I actually realize that this source changed a bit in the latest version of simple_form and are now looking the source for 2.1 instead of 3.0.0.rc to better understand how to deal with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a block:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_radio_buttons :rating, [[1, 'Bad'] ,[2, 'Ok'], [3, 'Great']],
                             :first, :last, { item_wrapper_tag: false } do |b|
    b.radio_button + b.label(:class => "collection_radio_buttons icon-star")
  end
end
```

This doc can showcase some other example: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_radio_buttons

Comment: Searched for this answer for hours. If you want to add the class to the input radio buttons, which is what I was looking for, use this:         `b.radio_button(:class => "collection_radio_buttons icon-star") + b.label(:class => "collection_radio_buttons icon-star")`

Comment: This doesn't work any more. All it will do is make your labels disappear completely.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wonders how to add class to label wrapping radiobutton input when you set `boolean_style = :nested` here is what I came with:

You can set option called `:item_label_class` when calling your input, f.e.:

```
<%= f.input :type, as: :radio_buttons,
                   collection: Listing::TYPES.map{ |type| [Listing.translate_type(type), type] },
                   label: false,
                   item_label_class: 'radio' %>
```

I wanted to automate this stuff, so I defined custom `CollectionRadioButtonsInput` class. You need to add to method `apply_default_collection_options!`:

```
def apply_default_collection_options!(options)
  super(options)
  options[:item_label_class] == 'radio' if input_type == :radio_buttons
end
```