# How to use enum in collection_radio_buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a model enum, `status`, how would it be used in `collection_radio_buttons`?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:rejected, :approved, :pending]
end
```

Comment: similar one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190111/simple-forms-collection-radio-button-and-custom-label-class

Comment: similar, not the same... not familiar with simple form... also, collection_radio_buttons isn't tied to a resource (ie., form_for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do something like below

```
<%= collection_radio_buttons(:project, :status, Project.statuses, :first, :first)%>
```

Comment: Great job, thank you. In your answer the radio buttons appear correctly; however, the form will post as project[status]=reject/approved/pending... and doesn't tie, to a resource (a project id). So, I had to do the following, where 't' is a member of the project collection: `<%= collection_radio_buttons(:project, t.id, Project.statuses, :first, :first, checked: t.status)%>`