# Simple Form Adding A Group Label To Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

So I have the following code:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :sex, [['male', 'Male'], ['female', 'Female']], :first, :last %>
```

I would like to add a 'Gender' label to the group. Any thoughts on best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17193162/5025116)?

Comment: Did you try `f.label :sex, "Gender"`? Radio buttons have different behaviour than `select`, so I think `label` is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Place

```
<%= f.label :sex, 'Gender' %>
```

above radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Pease see the docs for options_for_select()https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select for usage examples.

```
options_for_select(['Male', 'Female'], f.object.sex)
options_for_select(['Male', 'Female'], :selected => f.object.sex)
```

Alternatively, you can do this, which will already use the sex() value for your form object:

```
<%= f.select :sex, ['Male', 'Female'] %>
```

You can use the radio_button_tag helper.

Using your example, it's something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :sex, 'Sex' %>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <%= radio_button_tag('options', 'male', params[:options] == 'male') %>
        Value1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <%= radio_button_tag('options', 'Female', params[:options] == 'Female') %>
        Value2
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SimpleForm, why not use its helper:

```
<%= f.input, :sex, label: "Gender", as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['Male', 'male'], ['Female', 'female']], value_method: :last, label_method: :last %>
```

In fact here `:value_method` and `label_method` won't be necessary as it'll be the default behavior.

It'll also be a good idea to refactor your collection out to a helper somewhere instead of mixing it in your view.